# Align divs vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a trouble with my html page.
I have 3 sections : header, wrapper and footer, and I would like these three sections to be aligned vertically.
But the problem is my section five isn't inside my section wrapper, but under it, at the same level than the section footer

Here is my HTML page :

```
<<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        <!-- Header-->
        <section id="header">
        </section>
        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <section id="wrapper">
            <section id="initial">
            </section>
            <!-- Main -->
            <div id="main">
                <!-- Prices -->
                <section id="one">
                    <section id="two">
                    </section>
                    <section id="three">
                    </section>
                </section>
                <section id="four">
                </section>
            </div>
            <section id="five">
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="footer">
        </section>
    </body> 
</html>


#wrapper {
    transition : transform 0.5s;
    padding: 44px 0 1px 0;
    border :0;
    font-size : 100%;
    font : inherit;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    display :block;
    height : 990px;
}

#footer {
    background-image: url("../img/logos.png");
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height : 100px;
    font-size : 200%;
    text-align: center;
}

#main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: on what browser? looks fine to me in jsfiddle on firefox

Comment: Looks good to me in jsfiddle on chrome.

Comment: So you say that the footer section is in your wrapper?

Comment: I mean that the section five should be inside my wrapper, but it is under it, at the same position than section footer.

Comment: `@saloua` Please create a `jsfiddle` for you que, for quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kp6m4gxv/) is the effect that you want:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<div id="main" role="main">
    <section id="one">
        <h2>Section Heading One</h2>        
    </section>
    <section id="two">
        <h2>Section Heading Two</h2>        
    </section>
    <section id="three">
        <h2>Section Heading Three</h2>        
    </section>
    <section id="four">
        <h2>Section Heading Four</h2>        
    </section>
    <section id="five">
        <h2>Section Heading Five</h2>        
    </section>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>Footer</p>    
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    text-align: center;

    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#main
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    background-color: khaki;
}

section
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

footer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    text-align: center;

    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```